# modifiy grep output with find and replace cmd

Tags: unix

I use grep to sort log big file into small one but still there is long dir path in output log file which is common every time.I have to do find and replace every time.

Isnt there any way i can grep -r "format" log.log | execute `findnreplce` thing?

Comment: `grep` with recursive flag on a file makes no sense at all.

Comment: You could make use of the `-o` option to `grep` possibly (if you provided enough information).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Sed` will do what you want. Basic syntax to replace all the matches of foo with bar in-place in $file is:

`sed -i 's/foo/bar/g' $file`

If you're just wanting to delete rather than replace, simply leave out the 'bar' (so s/foo//g).

See [this tutorial](http://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Sed.html) for a lot more detail, such as regex support.

Answer (score 0):

```
sed -n '/match/s/pattern/repl/p'
```

Will print all the lines that match the regex `match`, with all instances of `pattern` replaced by `repl`.  Since your lines may contain paths, you will probably want to use a different delimeter. `/` is customary, but you can also do:

```
sed -n '\@match@s@@repl@p`
```

In the second case, omitting `pattern` will cause `match` to be used for the pattern to be replaced.